# Reduce size of OnsenUI

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, web-frameworks, onsen-ui

I just downloaded Onsen UI. It looks really nice, but is huge! So there are basically 3 questions:

- how can I strip down Onsen UI to a bare minimum?
- is AngularJS required to use Onsen UI? (I prefer knockoutjs)
- the Onsen UI 'minimum' example is already approx 6MB in size (without any gimmicks). Is there a *real* 'minimum' sample?

Answer (score 1):

### Size

The minimum template in getting started page is only 2.3mb.

http://onsenui.io/OnsenUI/project_templates/minimum.zip

http://onsenui.io/getting_started/

### AngularJS requirement

Onsen UI is based on http://Topcoat.io
So you can use the css without AngularJS.
But you need to adapt the animation logic for knockoutjs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but to tell you the truth: 2.3MB for a bare minimum template is way to huge. It's not the file-size that scares me, but all the sources must get processed and so the likeliness to run into performance issues rises from byte to byte ;)

Comment: @AndyFuchs When you decide to use a framework, you're tipping the balance of performance and ease-of-use to some extent. That's not a bad thing, just something to consider. So, a handful of MB for a framework that speeds up development time is not a bad tradeoff, especially given that I wouldn't consider Onsen UI to be "slow" by any means.  A good chunk of this is going to be JS and CSS that once initially loaded and parsed it's going to not get loaded and parsed again until a full load is needed; Onsen is going to pull in additional resources as needed on-the-fly.

Comment: @jzimmerman2011: that might be correct from a php-guy's pov, but it's absolutely not my opinion. I was talking (more than a year ago) about fast page-load when entering the webapp the very first time. So 3.2MB is a nogo. While you're absolutely right concerning the tradeoff, but there must be an alternative loading method, which first only loads the things absolutely required and then asynchronously the rest (remember: everything is rendered on the client). So file-size is still a crucial factor and quite often I tend to leaner solutions (e.g. zepto, knockout, etc...)